# How to set flash message in sonata admin Admin Controller

Tags: php, symfony, admin, sonata-admin, flash-message

im looking for a way to set flash message in admin controller of sonata admin bundle, they allow to set flash messages in CRUDController as

```
$this->get('session')->setFlash('sonata_flash_error', 'flash_batch_merge_error');
```

but not in the Admin Controller,

this is my admin contrller

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

class ConfigAdmin extends Admin
{

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{   

    $formMapper
        ->with('System Settings')
            ->add('Name','text', array('label' => "Configuration Name"))
            ->add('Language', 'choice', array(
                'label' => 'System Language',
                'choices' => array(0 => 'English', 1 => 'Swedish'),
                'preferred_choices' => array(0),
                ))
            ->add('commonmail','text', array('label' => "Common e-Mail"))
            ->add('dateformat','text', array('label' => "Date format"))
            ->add('currencyformat','text', array('label' => "Currency format"))
        ->end()
}

public function postUpdate($object) {

      // here i need to perform some validations and set flash message if there is an errror 

}

}
```

appreciate your help

Comment: What do you mean by "admin controller" ?

Comment: hey, i modified my issue hope this will make sense what i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about an admin class, not a controller.

And this is not possible by default. Best way to do this is to write a custom CRUDController (extend from default one) and handle it there.

Comment: incorrect answer that shouldn't be the accepted one : as described in other answers, you can inject the session service to use the flashbag in any class where you can inject services, including Sonata admin classes.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you can set a flash message in an admin class. First, [you can define a custom flash message type for the SonataCoreBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/flash_messages.html). For example, if you want a success flash message type, add this in the `app/config/config.yml` file:

```
sonata_core:
    flashmessage:
        success:
            types:
                - { type: mytodo_success, domain: MyToDoBundle }
```

Then, you need to know when to set the message. For example, if you want to set the message after creating a new entity, you can do so overriding the `postPersist` function in your admin class, and adding the message in the Symfony flash bag:

```
public function postPersist($object) {
    $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add("mytodo_success", "My To-Do custom success message");
}
```

This way, the message will be displayed whenever you create a new entity at the admin class.

You can also use the default type success:

```
public function postPersist($object) {
    $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add("success", "My To-Do custom success message");
}
```

Comment: yes , ->add("success",..) is sucessfull for me with sonata

Comment: "success", "warning" and "error" types seems to be supported in sonata

Comment: The problem is that you get at last two messages, the new added one, and the one by default. How to override or remove the default one ?

Answer (score 4):

Because it is an Admin class I get the flashbag over the Session service:

```
protected function whereever()
{
    $this->getFlashBag()->add(
        'info',
        'Your message'
    );
}
...
protected function getFlashBag()
{
    return $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('session')->getFlashBag();
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You need to inject the **session** service into your admin class.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services